# How can I solve this mysql error after upgrade

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.7

I upgraded from Godaddy to blue host and now I'm getting this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'customeTable.fromuser' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' in

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM(SELECT DISTINCT(thread_id) AS 
thread_id, fromuser, touser, aDeleted, bDeleted, avatar, message, seen, 
time FROM conversations WHERE fromuser=:username AND bDeleted=0 OR 
touser=:username AND aDeleted =0 ORDER BY time DESC) customeTable GROUP 
BY thread_id ORDER BY time DESC");

$statement->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Change the strictness, or probably more logical put the columns you are aggregating in the select list. You changed mysql versions, you now are running 5.7.

Comment: Ended up disabling only_full_group_by, all fixed now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the query take a look at following things:

- The query has a `GROUP BY`-clause without any aggregate function (you should probably remove it). See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).
- The `DISTINCT`modifier is not a function. It removes duplicate rows over all columns
- As the query is mixing `AND` and `OR` it should use parentheses, otherwise you might get unexpected results
- The subquery is not needed, you can remove it